# Rust reqwest: how to wait until the page is fully loaded?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to GET a website with reqwest libary.

The problem is some websites will be fully rendered in few milliseconds or around one second. (like table elements are loaded after html is rendered)

```rust
let client = reqwest::Client::builder()
    .danger_accept_invalid_certs(true)
    .timeout(Duration::from_secs(5))
    .connect_timeout(Duration::from_secs(2))
    .user_agent("User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36")
    .build()?;

let res = client.get(PROBLEM_WEBSITE).send().await?;

let body = res.text().await?;
```

Or like selenium, wait until an element is visible/shown?

So I want to wait a specific time but I'm not sure if there's a way.

Tried `tokio::time::sleep` after `res` but obviously it wasn't a solution.

(timeout, connect_timeout didn't affect anything)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reqwest does not do this, it only loads the data at a given URL and nothing more. What you ask for is what a browser displays when loading a webpage which will include loading other assets, embedding pages, running scripts, etc.

You need a full-on browser to get this functionality, which will require a web-driver (like selenium). Just looking around for Rust solutions, maybe [`fantoccini`](https://crates.io/crates/fantoccini) or [`chromiumoxide`](https://crates.io/crates/chromiumoxide) or [`headless_chrome`](https://crates.io/crates/headless_chrome) catch your fancy.